# How do I make a pool cue rotate around the cue ball?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want the pool cue to rotate around the cue ball as the player drags the mouse, I've played some pool games on the internet and they all seem to work this way. This will eventually be a browser game.

This game isn't mine, but it has the basic mechanic that I want (I don't care about the lines that are displayed, I just want the rotate and hit mechanic) https://www.crazygames.com/game/8-ball-billiards-classic

I have tried some orbiting scripts so far, none of them work.

I've tried some scripts that make objects orbit based on time hoping to make it so it orbits with the mouse dragging instead of time. I also can't get the cue to constantly face the cue ball.

This code has gotten me the closest.

```
public int vertexCount = 40;
    public float lineWidth = 0.2f;
    public float radius;
    public bool circleFillscreen;
    //circle variables
    static float timeCounter = 0;
    float width;
    float height;

    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        SetupCircle();
    }

    void Update()
    {

        timeCounter += Time.deltaTime;

        float x = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter);
        float y = 0;
        float z = Mathf.Sin(timeCounter);



    }



    private void SetupCircle()
    {
        lineRenderer.widthMultiplier = lineWidth;

        if (circleFillscreen)
        {
            radius = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, Camera.main.pixelRect.yMax, 0f)),
                Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, Camera.main.pixelRect.yMin, 0f))) * 0.5f - lineWidth;
        }

        float deltaTheta = (2f * Mathf.PI) / vertexCount;
        float theta = 0F;

        lineRenderer.positionCount = -vertexCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < lineRenderer.positionCount; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(radius * Mathf.Cos(theta), radius * Mathf.Sin(theta), 0f);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, pos);
            theta += deltaTheta;

        }



    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        float deltaTheta = (2f * Mathf.PI) / vertexCount;
        float theta = 0f;

        Vector3 oldPos = Vector3.zero; 
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount + 1; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(radius * Mathf.Cos(theta), 0F,radius * Mathf.Sin(theta));
            Gizmos.DrawLine(oldPos, transform.position + pos);
            oldPos = transform.position + pos;

            theta += deltaTheta;

        }

    }
#endif

}
```

Not really getting any error messages, code "works" but doesn't work.

Comment: Clever parenting. An empty game object will do wonders.